# The dropdown menu button stays open and won't close

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got a dropdown menu button and when clicked on the icon it should open and when clicking off the icon or on the icon then it should close again, but instead it stays open.

Here is a screenshot, to what i am referring too.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX328.jpg

I have researched regarding this issue, but i am unable to find a solution.

My CSS is on paste bin at https://pastebin.com/BHXNjtWJ

This is because the CSS is to long to fit on here.

My HTML is:

```
<body class="twoCol react menuOpen" data-tippy-delegate="">
    <div id="fb-root"></div> 
    <div id="app-root" class="notranslate" data-tippy-delegate="">
        <div class="Master__wrap__22Bnx en-US">
            <div class="NavigationTop__wrap__fQdBR">
                <div class="NavigationTop__inner__1LxZ7" data-ui-name="headerNavigation">
                    <ul class="NavigationMain__nav__3NRm2">
                        <li class="NavigationMain__signUp__2YtN8"><a href="https://signin.rockstargames.com/create/?cid=socialclub&amp;lang=en-US&amp;returnUrl=%2F" class="NavigationMain__navLink__1xmUY NavigationMain__navLinkHighlight__pgt2K" data-ui-name="signUp">Sign Up</a></li>

                        <li class="NavigationMain__signIn__3thGS"><a href="https://signin.rockstargames.com/connect/authorize/socialclub?lang=en-US&amp;returnUrl=%2F" class="NavigationMain__navLink__1xmUY" data-ui-name="signIn">Sign In</a></li>

                        <li><a class="NavigationMain__navLink__1xmUY" data-ui-name="games" href="/games">Games<span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" height="16" width="16" class="NavigationMain__navLinkToggle__2xOGg"><path d="M16 25.9c-.4 0-.8-.2-1-.5L.3 8.4c-.5-.6-.4-1.4.2-1.9.6-.5 1.4-.5 1.9.1L16 22.4 29.6 6.6c.5-.6 1.3-.6 1.9-.1.6.5.6 1.4.1 1.9L17 25.4c-.2.3-.6.5-1 .5z"></path></svg></span></a>

                        <ul class="NavigationMain__navSub__3W27M"><li><a class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" data-ui-name="rdr2" href="#">Title<span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" height="16" width="16" class="NavigationMain__navLinkToggle__2xOGg">
                                <path d="M16 25.9c-.4 0-.8-.2-1-.5L.3 8.4c-.5-.6-.4-1.4.2-1.9.6-.5 1.4-.5 1.9.1L16 22.4 29.6 6.6c.5-.6 1.3-.6 1.9-.1.6.5.6 1.4.1 1.9L17 25.4c-.2.3-.6.5-1 .5z"></path></svg></span></a>

                        <ul class="NavigationMain__navSubSub__2bkYi">
                            <li><a class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" href="#">Title</a></li>

                            <li><a class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" href="#">Story</a></li>

                            <li><a class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" href="#">Title</a></li>

                            <li><a class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" href="#">Title</a></li>

                            <li><a class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" href="Title">Title</a></li>

                            <li><a class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" href="#">Title</a></li>

                            <li><a class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" href="#">Title</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" data-ui-name="gtav">Title<span>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" height="16" width="16" class="NavigationMain__navLinkToggle__2xOGg"><path d="M16 25.9c-.4 0-.8-.2-1-.5L.3 8.4c-.5-.6-.4-1.4.2-1.9.6-.5 1.4-.5 1.9.1L16 22.4 29.6 6.6c.5-.6 1.3-.6 1.9-.1.6.5.6 1.4.1 1.9L17 25.4c-.2.3-.6.5-1 .5z"></path></svg></span></a>

                        <ul class="NavigationMain__navSubSub__2bkYi">
                            <li><a href="#" class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" data-ui-name="gtavCareer">Title</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#" class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" data-ui-name="gtavAccomplishments">Title</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#" class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" data-ui-name="gtavTutorials">Title</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#" class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" data-ui-name="playlists">Playlists</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" data-ui-name="lan">Title</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#" class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" data-ui-name="lanvr">Title</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#" class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" data-ui-name="bully">Title</a></li>

                    <li><a class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" data-ui-name="allGames" href="/games">All Games</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="NavigationMain__overlay__3SibJ"></div></li><li><a class="NavigationMain__navLink__1xmUY" data-ui-name="crews" href="/crews">Title<span>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" height="16" width="16" class="NavigationMain__navLinkToggle__2xOGg"><path d="M16 25.9c-.4 0-.8-.2-1-.5L.3 8.4c-.5-.6-.4-1.4.2-1.9.6-.5 1.4-.5 1.9.1L16 22.4 29.6 6.6c.5-.6 1.3-.6 1.9-.1.6.5.6 1.4.1 1.9L17 25.4c-.2.3-.6.5-1 .5z"></path></svg></span></a>

                    <ul class="NavigationMain__navSub__3W27M"><li><a class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" data-ui-name="crewSearch" href="/crews">Search</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" data-ui-name="myCrews">Create a Title</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#" class="NavigationMain__navLinkSub__2T3V5" data-ui-name="emblemEditor">Title Editor</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="NavigationMain__overlay__3SibJ">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="NavigationMain__navLink__1xmUY" data-ui-name="jobs" href="/jobs">Jobs</a></li>

                <li><a class="NavigationMain__navLink__1xmUY" data-ui-name="photos" href="/photos">Photos</a></li>

                <li><a class="NavigationMain__navLink__1xmUY" data-ui-name="videos" href="/videos">Videos</a></li>

                <li><a href="/events" class="NavigationMain__navLink__1xmUY" data-ui-name="events">Events</a></li>

                <li><a href="#" class="NavigationMain__navLink__1xmUY" data-ui-name="news" target="_blank">News</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="NavigationTop__groupLeft__3lTQW">
                <a href="#" class="NavigationTop__icon__32Kg3 NavigationTop__hamburger__KU-ur">
                    <span class="NavigationTop__iconBg__3nlrW">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" height="16" width="16" class="UI__Icon__icon"><path d="M24.8 10.6H7.3c-.8 0-1.4-.6-1.4-1.4 0-.8.6-1.4 1.4-1.4h17.5c.8 0 1.4.6 1.4 1.4 0 .8-.6 1.4-1.4 1.4zM24.9 17.3H7.4c-.8 0-1.4-.6-1.4-1.4s.6-1.4 1.4-1.4h17.5c.8 0 1.4.6 1.4 1.4s-.7 1.4-1.4 1.4zM24.9 24H7.4c-.8 0-1.4-.6-1.4-1.4s.6-1.4 1.4-1.4h17.5c.8 0 1.4.6 1.4 1.4s-.7 1.4-1.4 1.4z"></path><path d="M25.1 32H3.3C1.5 32 0 30.5 0 28.7V3.3C0 1.5 1.5 0 3.3 0h25.3C30.5 0 32 1.5 32 3.3v21.9c0 .8-.6 1.4-1.4 1.4-.8 0-1.4-.6-1.4-1.4V3.3c0-.3-.3-.6-.6-.6H3.3c-.3 0-.6.3-.6.6v25.3c0 .3.3.6.6.6h21.8c.8 0 1.4.6 1.4 1.4 0 .8-.6 1.4-1.4 1.4z"></path></svg></span></a><ul class="NavigationTop__nav__1InFQ NavigationTop__navSignedOut__2qibz">

                            <li><a href="#" class="NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP" data-ui-name="signIn">Sign In</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#" class="NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP NavigationTop__navLinkHighlight__2uEEp" data-ui-name="signUp">Sign Up</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#" class="NavigationTop__icon__32Kg3 NavigationTop__search__UDzfT" data-ui-name="scSearch"><span class="NavigationTop__iconBg__3nlrW"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" height="16" width="16" class="UI__Icon__icon"><path d="M30.5 32c-.4 0-.8-.1-1.1-.4l-9.3-9.3c-.6-.6-.6-1.5 0-2.1 3.9-4 3.9-10.3 0-14.2-1.9-1.9-4.4-3-7.1-3-2.6 0-5.1 1.1-7 3-3.9 3.9-3.9 10.2 0 14.1 2.4 2.4 5.7 3.4 9 2.7.8-.1 1.6.4 1.8 1.2.2.8-.4 1.6-1.2 1.8-4.3.8-8.7-.5-11.7-3.6-5.1-5.1-5.1-13.4 0-18.5C6.3 1.4 9.6 0 13 0c3.5 0 6.8 1.4 9.2 3.8 4.7 4.7 5.1 12.2 1 17.3l8.3 8.3c.6.6.6 1.5 0 2.1-.2.4-.6.5-1 .5z"></path></svg></span></a>
                    </div>
                    <a class="NavigationTop__logo__3GmAs" data-ui-name="logo" href="/">
                        <div class="NavigationTop__logoRockstar__1m1Ou">
                        </div>
                        <div class="NavigationTop__logoSocialClub__1EfPy">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="NavigationTop__groupRight__3UIqi"><span class="NavigationTop__navPlayer__2TGn7"><a href="#" class="NavigationTop__icon__32Kg3" data-ui-name="info"><span class="NavigationTop__iconBg__3nlrW">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" height="16" width="16" class="UI__Icon__icon"><path d="M15.6 32s-.1 0 0 0h-.8c-2.7 0-5.6 0-8.4-.8-3-.9-4.6-2.4-4.7-4.7-.1-1.1.3-2.2 1-3.1 1.1-1.5 2.7-2.4 4.1-3.1.5-.3 1-.5 1.5-.8.6-.4 2-1.4 2.1-2.7 0-.6-.2-1.3-.8-2.1l-.6-.9c-.4-.6-.8-1.2-1.2-1.9-1.2-2.5-1-5.6.4-7.9.2-.3.4-.6.7-.9 1.8-2 4.3-3.1 7-3.1 2.7-.1 5.3 1.1 7.2 3 .3.3.6.7.8 1 1.4 2.3 1.5 5.4.3 7.9-.4.7-.8 1.3-1.2 1.9l-.6.9c-.5.8-.8 1.5-.8 2.1.1 1.3 1.5 2.3 2.1 2.7.5.3 1 .6 1.5.8 1.4.7 3 1.5 4.1 3.1.7.9 1 2.1 1 3.1-.1 2.2-1.7 3.8-4.7 4.7-.7.2-1.4.3-2 .5-.7.1-1.5-.4-1.6-1.1-.1-.7.4-1.5 1.1-1.6.6-.1 1.2-.2 1.7-.4 2.4-.7 2.7-1.5 2.7-2.2 0-.5-.1-.9-.5-1.4-.7-1-1.9-1.6-3.1-2.3-.6-.3-1.1-.6-1.7-.9-2.1-1.3-3.3-3-3.4-4.9-.1-1.2.3-2.4 1.2-3.8.2-.3.4-.7.7-1 .4-.5.7-1 1-1.5.8-1.6.7-3.6-.2-5.2-.1-.1-.2-.2-.4-.5-1.3-1.4-3.2-2.2-5.2-2.2-1.9 0-3.7.8-5 2.2-.2.2-.3.4-.4.5-.9 1.6-1 3.6-.2 5.2.3.5.6 1 1 1.5.2.3.5.6.7 1 .9 1.3 1.3 2.6 1.2 3.8-.1 1.9-1.3 3.6-3.4 4.9-.5.3-1.1.6-1.7.9C6.9 23.4 5.7 24 5 25c-.3.4-.5.9-.5 1.4 0 .7.4 1.5 2.7 2.2 2.4.7 4.9.7 7.6.7h.8c.4 0 .8.2 1 .5.3.3.4.7.3 1.1 0 .6-.6 1.1-1.3 1.1z"></path></svg></span></a>
                        <div class="NavigationPlayer__nav__1GtYE NavigationPlayer__navOpen__kmIqC"><ul class="NavigationPlayer__navSub__SIRkf"><li class="NavigationPlayer__signUp__2AOMK"><a href="https://signin.rockstargames.com/create/?cid=socialclub&amp;lang=en-US&amp;returnUrl=%2F" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj NavigationPlayer__highlight__2lzxA" data-ui-name="signUp">Sign Up</a></li>

                            <li class="NavigationPlayer__signIn__3qaVH"><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="signIn">Sign In</a></li><li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="legal">Legal</a></li><li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="privacy">Privacy</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="support">Support</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="cookies">Cookies</a></li>

                            <li><div class="NavigationPlayer__languageWrap__2jmcz">
                                <div class="UI__DropDown__custom-select LanguageSelector__dropdown__2uNdg">
                                    <select class="select" data-ui-name="languageSelector">
                                        <option value="de-DE">Deutsch</option>
                                        <option value="en-US">English</option>
                                        <option value="es-ES">Español</option>
                                        <option value="es-MX">Español Latinoamérica</option>
                                        <option value="fr-FR">Français</option>
                                        <option value="it-IT">Italiano</option>
                                        <option value="ja-JP">日本語</option>
                                        <option value="ko-KR">한국어</option>
                                        <option value="pl-PL">Polski</option>
                                        <option value="pt-BR">Português do Brasil</option>
                                        <option value="ru-RU">Русский</option>
                                        <option value="zh-TW">繁體中文</option>
                                        <option value="zh-CN">简体中文</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
```

Updated code below:

```
<div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="NavigationTop__groupRight__3UIqi"><span class="NavigationTop__navPlayer__2TGn7"><a onclick="myFunction()" href="#" class="NavigationTop__icon__32Kg3" data-ui-name="info"><span class="NavigationTop__iconBg__3nlrW" class="dropbtn">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" height="16" width="16" class="UI__Icon__icon"><path d="M15.6 32s-.1 0 0 0h-.8c-2.7 0-5.6 0-8.4-.8-3-.9-4.6-2.4-4.7-4.7-.1-1.1.3-2.2 1-3.1 1.1-1.5 2.7-2.4 4.1-3.1.5-.3 1-.5 1.5-.8.6-.4 2-1.4 2.1-2.7 0-.6-.2-1.3-.8-2.1l-.6-.9c-.4-.6-.8-1.2-1.2-1.9-1.2-2.5-1-5.6.4-7.9.2-.3.4-.6.7-.9 1.8-2 4.3-3.1 7-3.1 2.7-.1 5.3 1.1 7.2 3 .3.3.6.7.8 1 1.4 2.3 1.5 5.4.3 7.9-.4.7-.8 1.3-1.2 1.9l-.6.9c-.5.8-.8 1.5-.8 2.1.1 1.3 1.5 2.3 2.1 2.7.5.3 1 .6 1.5.8 1.4.7 3 1.5 4.1 3.1.7.9 1 2.1 1 3.1-.1 2.2-1.7 3.8-4.7 4.7-.7.2-1.4.3-2 .5-.7.1-1.5-.4-1.6-1.1-.1-.7.4-1.5 1.1-1.6.6-.1 1.2-.2 1.7-.4 2.4-.7 2.7-1.5 2.7-2.2 0-.5-.1-.9-.5-1.4-.7-1-1.9-1.6-3.1-2.3-.6-.3-1.1-.6-1.7-.9-2.1-1.3-3.3-3-3.4-4.9-.1-1.2.3-2.4 1.2-3.8.2-.3.4-.7.7-1 .4-.5.7-1 1-1.5.8-1.6.7-3.6-.2-5.2-.1-.1-.2-.2-.4-.5-1.3-1.4-3.2-2.2-5.2-2.2-1.9 0-3.7.8-5 2.2-.2.2-.3.4-.4.5-.9 1.6-1 3.6-.2 5.2.3.5.6 1 1 1.5.2.3.5.6.7 1 .9 1.3 1.3 2.6 1.2 3.8-.1 1.9-1.3 3.6-3.4 4.9-.5.3-1.1.6-1.7.9C6.9 23.4 5.7 24 5 25c-.3.4-.5.9-.5 1.4 0 .7.4 1.5 2.7 2.2 2.4.7 4.9.7 7.6.7h.8c.4 0 .8.2 1 .5.3.3.4.7.3 1.1 0 .6-.6 1.1-1.3 1.1z"></path></svg></span></a>
                        <div class="NavigationPlayer__nav__1GtYE NavigationPlayer__navOpen__kmIqC"><ul class="NavigationPlayer__navSub__SIRkf"><li class="NavigationPlayer__signUp__2AOMK"><a href="https://signin.rockstargames.com/create/?cid=socialclub&amp;lang=en-US&amp;returnUrl=%2F" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj NavigationPlayer__highlight__2lzxA" data-ui-name="signUp">Sign Up</a></li>

                            <li class="NavigationPlayer__signIn__3qaVH"><a href="https://signin.rockstargames.com/connect/authorize/socialclub?lang=en-US&amp;returnUrl=%2F" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="signIn">Sign In</a></li>
                            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"
                            <li><a href="https://www.rockstargames.com/legal" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="legal">Legal</a></li>

                            <li><a href="https://www.rockstargames.com/privacy" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="privacy">Privacy</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="support">Support</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="cookies">Cookies</a></li>

                            <li><div class="NavigationPlayer__languageWrap__2jmcz">
                                <div class="UI__DropDown__custom-select LanguageSelector__dropdown__2uNdg">
                                    <select class="select" data-ui-name="languageSelector">
                                        <option value="de-DE">Deutsch</option>
                                        <option value="en-US">English</option>
                                        <option value="es-ES">Español</option>
                                        <option value="es-MX">Español Latinoamérica</option>
                                        <option value="fr-FR">Français</option>
                                        <option value="it-IT">Italiano</option>
                                        <option value="ja-JP">日本語</option>
                                        <option value="ko-KR">한국어</option>
                                        <option value="pl-PL">Polski</option>
                                        <option value="pt-BR">Português do Brasil</option>
                                        <option value="ru-RU">Русский</option>
                                        <option value="zh-TW">繁體中文</option>
                                        <option value="zh-CN">简体中文</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you reduce your code to the point it is easy to read and reproduce the problem

Comment: @CoderJoe will I just post the code for the problem, wich is the dropdown icon button?

Comment: if I run the code snippet I do not see the problem and it is different from your image therefor you will need to edit your post so that people can reproduce the issue you are experiencing

Comment: for that to happen will need to upload the full code and it is lengthy

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show

Comment: You need to attach an event listener on the toggle. The event listener tells JS to pay attention to that element and do something when X happens (e.g., when a user clicks). In this case the "something" might be to add a class to the menu (e.g., `.active` or `.open`) unless the class is already present, in which case it should remove the class. That class should control whether the menu is visible or not. Something along those lines.

Comment: @CoderJoe I have updated the code above

Comment: @denmch done that, but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

You just remove the "show" class but that is not enough to hide the element again.

Create another CSS class called "hide" that does `display:none, and when you remove the show class, add the hide class right after.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer to the question. Also, I always recommend _not_ to do as you suggest -- one class that is added/removed is sufficient.